# Por que cuando hago un push de mi proyecto a Github aparece la carpeta principal?

Tags: git, github

Estoy tratando de hacer push de un proyecto pero al momento de hacer push a Github se sube la carpeta principal del proyecto y yo quiero que se vean los archivos al entrar al repositorio no la carpeta principal.

Se me esta subiendo al repositorio de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo quiero que se vea de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que debiste proceder del siguiente modo:

Cuando ya tienes creado tu repositorio en github, lo clonas en local de la siguiente manera:

```
git clone https://github.com/tuUsuario/bingo.git
```

Cuando ya tienes dicha copia de tu repositorio, entonces deberás copiar solamente los archivos de tu proyecto local, mas no la carpeta completa; de tal modo que en local tengas:

```
Bingo <--- Esta es la carpeta del repositorio que acabas de clonar
    archivo1.html  --> Estos son los archivos locales que quieres subir a dicho repo
    archivo2.txt
    archivo3.foo
```

Finalmente haces:

- git add .
- git commit -m "tu mensaje"
- git push origin master

Y ya deberías tener una vista similar a la que buscas con la última imagen